# jackson readTree ignore nulls

Tags: java, jackson

When using readTree in jackson parser I'd like it to ignore keys that correspond to null values. Or alternatively recreate the tree without the null mappings.

Json:

```
{
"elm1" : "val1",
"elm2" : null
}
```

Parsed tree:

```
{
"elm1" : "val1"
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

To recreate the tree without null mappings:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Set this property on your `ObjectMapper` before re-serializing the tree.

Comment: This is a serialization property, meaning it applies to the json string, not to the json tree (i.e. the `JsonNode` object). Is there a similar setting that avoids putting the key into the tree in memory?